# How do I connect two keras models into one model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet, vgg-net

Let's say I have a ResNet50 model and I wish to connect the output layer of this model to the input layer of a VGG model.

This is the ResNet model and the output tensor of ResNet50:

```
img_shape = (164, 164, 3)
resnet50_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, input_shape=img_shape, weights = None)

print(resnet50_model.output.shape)
```

I get the output:

```
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(6), Dimension(6), Dimension(2048)])
```

Now I want a new layer where I reshape this output tensor to (64,64,18)

Then I have a VGG16 model:

```
VGG_model = VGG_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights=None)
```

I want the output of the ResNet50 to reshape into the desired tensor and fed in as an input to the VGG model. So essentially I want to concatenate two models. Can someone help me do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this. Here is one way of using Sequential model API to do it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50, VGG16

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
img_shape = (164, 164, 3)
model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, input_shape=img_shape, weights = None))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(64,64,18)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,kernel_size=(3,3),name='Conv2d'))

VGG_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights=None)
model.add(VGG_model)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Model summary is as follows

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
resnet50 (Model)             (None, 6, 6, 2048)        23587712  
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 64, 64, 18)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
Conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 62, 62, 3)         489       
_________________________________________________________________
vgg16 (Model)                multiple                  14714688  
=================================================================
Total params: 38,302,889
Trainable params: 38,249,769
Non-trainable params: 53,120
_________________________________________________________________
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/multi_model_ResNet_VGG.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you, if I may ask, how do we determine if the conv2d will output 3 channels? How do conv2d kernels transform the tensors into more than 3 channels?

Comment: In the above example, the layer before `conv2d` has 18  channels (filters), so i  defined filters=3 in `conv2d` and hence there were 3 channels formed.  You can change `filters` from 3 to any number to increase number of channels.