# How to connect this two model in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, pose

I'm trying to combine Posenet with my custom model.
The input of this custom model is:

```
Tensor("dense_Dense1_input:0", shape=(?, 34), dtype=float32)
```

However, the problem is that the outputs of the posenet to be received is different

The input of this custom model has the values ​​of 17 keypoints of Posenet listed in xy order.

The output of this posenet is:

```
<tf.Tensor 'tf_op_layer_heatmap/heatmap:0' shape=(?, 23, 23, 17) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'offset_2/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 23, 23, 34) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'displacement_fwd_2/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 23, 23, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'displacement_bwd_2/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 23, 23, 32) dtype=float32>
```

How can I make these two models together?

this is graph of the models:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIEgB.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0121x.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNvLX.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOohF.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by together? Also please full code before asking these questions.

Comment: Kindly share the model architectures along with the code.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi I uploaded graphs of these models.
Can't you check these out?

Comment: @Rohit I uploaded graphs of these models.
Can't you check these out?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446429/how-do-i-connect-two-keras-models-into-one-model/61450306#61450306) which is what you are looking.

Comment: @VishnuvardhanJanapati I need to calculate keypoints from those 4 outputs.
Calculating that, I need to list 17 keypoint xy coordinates and put them into the input of the target model.  Can I create a layer that calculates each 4 outputs?